Complex integral $\frac{\sin(z)}{z(z+1)^3}$
I have the following integral $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z(z+1)^3}$ taking $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ and considering the analytic continuation $F$ at $z=0$ with $F(0)=1$
, I'd obtain:
$$ \int_{|z|=2}\frac{F(z)}{(z+1)^3}dz=2\pi i \frac{F^{(2)}(-1)}{2!}=\pi i(-2\cos(1)+\sin(1))$$
And after checking the result at: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+isin%282exp%28ix%29%29%2F%282exp%28ix%29%2B1%29%5E3+dx+from+x%3D0+to+2pi
, I noticed that there is a very negliglible real amount in the result. Would it be a numerical issue? Any other suggestions for solving the integral above involving less computations?

If I use the substitution $z=2e^{i\theta}$ to get a direct integration, then Mathematica gives the result you obtained. So I would not take the real part as anything other than Wolfram Alpha not being immediately able to numerically verify that the result is imaginary.

The non-zero real part is indeed an artifact. See here

You can use numerical integration with more detailed options.
Analytically, e.g. in Mathematica, you get
   Integrate[Sin[2 E^(I s)]/(2 E^(I s) (2 E^(I s) + 1)^3) * 2 I E^(I s), 
            {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

$$-i \pi  (2 \cos (1)-\sin (1))$$
The same integral numerically
     NIntegrate[
      Sin[2 E^(I s)]/(2 E^(I s) (2 E^(I s) + 1)^3) * 2 I E^(I s), 
     {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}] 

        0. -0.75126 I

      NIntegrate[Sin[2 E^(I s)]/(2 E^(I s) (2 E^(I s) + 1)^3) 2 I E^(I s),
       {s, 0,  2 \[Pi]}, WorkingPrecision -> 12] 

   3.68239703834*10^-12 - 0.751260445521 I

The same with precision 64
      -0.7512604455844901604960990363391948318948321673188473652511599821 I

For a more 'complex analytical' approach, represent the rational by a sum of primitive fractions
$$\frac{a}{z}+\frac{b+c z+d z^2}{(z+1)^3}-\frac{1}{z (z+1)^3} =0$$
The coefficients are
$$a=1, \  b=-3, \ c=-3, \ d=-1$$
The term $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is analytical. The rest is, by the series around the singular point $z=-\frac{1}{2}$
$$\left(-\frac{1}{(2 z+1)^2}-\frac{7}{4 (2 z+1)^3}-\frac{1}{2 (2 z+1)}\right) \quad \sin (z)$$
Only the last term has a nonzero residue
    NIntegrate[Sin[2 E^(I s)] ( -(1/(2 (1 + 2 2 E^(I s)))) )* 
     2 I E^(I s), {s, 0,  2 \[Pi]}]

    5.55112*10^-17 + 0.75308 I

